# How to connect to localhost from Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, localhost

I am trying to test web application in Android 2.3.3 browser.
Connection using http://10.0.2.2 results **"web page is unavailable"**. Nothing found in **Android Studio** [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html).

Does anyone run into the same problem? How did you solve it?

Comment: ` http://10.0.2.2`. That is perfectly ok if you use an emulator and the webserver is on the same pc as your emulator is running on.

Comment: No, it is not, I tried. Seems that 10.0.2.2 was acceptable for ADT. Now it is Android Studio, rules changed.

Comment: And 404 means that the connection with the webserver was established. But the requested page was not found. And indeed you are not requesting a page or there is no default page. But 10.0.2.2 does connect!

Comment: That was my mistake. It wrote just **web page is unavailable**. I'll fix question, sorry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're going to need to connect to your computer's IP.

If you're on Windows open CMD and type ipconfig this will give you your local IP.

If you're on Linux or OSX open terminal and use the ifconfig command.

Since the emulator is a full Android device it has its own network and doesn't use the same hosts file that your machine has. Along with its own IP.

Edit: Grammar fix.

Comment: It is linux and that helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I use my local ip for that i.e. 192.168.0.1 and it works. Verify your local IP.