# Getting development device's IPv4 in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ipv4

I'm new to Xamarin Forms and C#. I'm working on a Xamarin Forms project and I want to write a function to get the IPv4 of the computer that I use for coding, not the virtual machine.

Comment: Hi! I don't know if there is a direct way of doing so. The app doesn't know if it's running on a VM or a real machine. The IP configuration of the VM can be the same that your machine, it can be inside the same subnet, or in a whole different network range.

Comment: Try either [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6760585/199364) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42904584/199364).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you, this is what I'm looking for

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313149/xamarin-forms-get-device-ip-address) :)